# Install DBAN to USB flash drive from Linux

Tags: usb, dban

I would like to install [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) to a USB flash drive to boot from on an old computer. How can I do this from an Ubuntu environment? `dd` image to USB device doesn't work

Comment: Does the vendor of the old computer (you don't mention vendor and model) allow a USB boot?

Comment: [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) works well for ISO to USB. Otherwise, does dd fail to image the USB device, or does the resulting image fail to boot, or something else?

Comment: @mdpc Of course ... it's not _that_ old.

Comment: Still can you identify the specific vendor and model number of the computer?

Comment: @mdpc Toshiba Satellite A135.

Answer (score 5):

It's an old question, and I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I managed to get it working following a comment on [this discussion](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1701757):

- Download [dban 2.3.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/dban/dban-2.3.0/dban-2.3.0_i586.iso/download)
- Install `unetbootin` (`sudo apt-get install unetbootin`)
- Install DBAN on a USB flash drive using unetbootin
- Mount the USB stick
- Replace every occurrence of `ubninit` with `ISOLINUX.BIN` in the `syslinux.cfg` file (`sed -i 's/ubninit/ISOLINUX.BIN/g' syslinux.cfg`)
- Replace every occurrence of `ubnkern` with `DBAN.BZI` in the `syslinux.cfg` file (`sed -i 's/ubnkern/DBAN.BZI/g' syslinux.cfg`)

**WARNING**: If you boot from this USB stick, **it will automatically start erasing your hard drive** (no input needed) after 10 seconds from the boot, so be sure to unplug it, and to plug it only where you need it.